# How to start tomcat before application context is resolved

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have an existing web application that computes the `ServletContext.contextPath` during the initialization of the spring context.

I made some modifications so the app now uses spring boot and within a normal tomcat it works as designed.

If I start the app from the command line the bean that computes the `ServletContext` is processed at a time where there is now servlet context available. The bean is "ready" even though there was no `onStartup(ServletContext)` event.

This is what happens:

1. Bean x implements FactoryBean, ServletContextAware
2. bean is created by spring and used by another bean y (getObject).
3. getObject returns null because the setServletContext has not been called.

I tried to inject the (web)application context into x which worked. But at the time the bean is used the servlet context in the webapplication context has not been set yet...

For debugging reasons i provided a dummy servlet context to see what happens next. Turned out the whole tomcat is started only after bean x and bean y are "ready" and started.

At first I have

```
- Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3972a855: startup date [Fri Dec 11 16:56:33 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
```

some times later I see the following entries in the logfile:

```
 Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
Dez 11, 2015 4:56:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Tomcat
Dez 11, 2015 4:56:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Dez 11, 2015 4:56:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

So, how do I declare my bean to be only ready after the complete web environment has been started?
Neither `ServletContextAware` nor `WebApplicationInitializer` do the trick.

So as of now I can use spring boot with an external tomcat, but not as executable jar, because my beans are marked as "ready" before all requirements have been met.

This is the stacktrace I get:

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:677)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101)
    at com.db.opra.boot.Starter.main(Starter.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myClass.servletContext.getContextPath(WebContextNameResolverFactory.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
```

Comment: Why are you computing the context path? It's configured via the `server.context-path` property and can be retrieved at runtime using `ServerProperties.getContextPath()`

Answer (score 0):

You can have your bean listen to `ContextRefreshed` [event](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2). It is easy, you need to add method annotated with @EventListener which takes `ContextRefreshedEvent` as a paramter:

```
 @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: No sorry, this is not called before the bean "ready", i just tried it.

Comment: What do you need exactly from servlet context?